# Mostrar informacion que no este en otra tabla

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, join

Estoy intentando traer datos que no se encuentren en otra tabla con `codeigniter`

Mi modelo:

```
public function getEntradas($proveedor){
            //Mostrar entradas del proveedor que no estan en pagos
            $this->db->select('e.id,e.cajas,e.peso,e.status,e.hora,e.fecha,h.nombre as nombre_huerta,r.nombre as nombre_proveedor');
            $this->db->from('entrada e');
            $this->db->distinct();
            $this->db->join('pagos p','e.id != p.identrada');
            $this->db->where('e.idproveedor',$proveedor);
            $this->db->join('huerta h','e.idhuerta = h.id');
            $this->db->join('proveedor r','e.idproveedor = r.id');
            $this->db->order_by('e.id','desc');
            $result = $this->db->get();
            return $result->result();
}
```

Esto me muestra toda la información el id `246` ya se encuentra en mi tabla `pagos` por lo tanto no debería mostrarse.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si esta linea la modifico :

```
$this->db->join('pagos p','e.id != p.identrada');
```

por:

```
$this->db->join('pagos p','e.id = p.identrada');
```

Solo me muestra la `246` a la inversa si aplica la logica pero porque no me funciona el `!=`

Mis tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo generado SQL:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
`e`.`id`, `e`.`cajas`, `e`.`peso`, `e`.`status`, `e`.`hora`, `e`.`fecha`, 
`h`.`nombre` as `nombre_huerta`, 
`r`.`nombre` as `nombre_proveedor` 
FROM `entrada` `e` 
INNER JOIN `pagos` `p` ON `p`.`identrada` != `e`.`id` JOIN `huerta` `h` ON `e`.`idhuerta` = `h`.`id` JOIN `proveedor` `r` ON `e`.`idproveedor` = `r`.`id` WHERE `e`.`idproveedor` = '79' ORDER BY `e`.`id` DESC
```

Comment: Prueba colocando el inner al final `$this->db->join('pagos p','e.id != p.identrada', 'inner');` si no estoy mal si no lo especificas se va un left por defecto

Comment: Me sigue apareciendo

Comment: Ok...una mejor idea, pon la estructura de tus tablas, y explica los registros que esperas obtener @Manuel Morales

Comment: listo he agregado mis dos tablas, ignora _idpago de entrada_

Comment: para ver cómo se está armando el sql agrega esto antes del return `$this->db->save_queries = TRUE; $sqlQuery = $this->db->last_query(); print_r($sqlQuery); die();`

Comment: listo! ya lo he agregado, checa los cambios